# Copy /etc/yum.repos.d/* to same directory on all computer without repetetively typing root password

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I want to normalise the yum.repo files for all computers on our small network i.e

```
sudo scp /etc/yum.repos.d/* $HOSTNAME:/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

I can loop through all hostnames easily enough and execute the command to copy, however I am prompted for the root password on each occasion which is becoming tiresome. How can I script this with bash or perl so that I only need to type the root command in once?

Comment: I think this question fits better on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement password-less authentication with ssh keys, as described [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152), for instance. This will allow to run scripts without password prompts using ssh key file in your home folder.

Comment: Would I not still need the root password to copy files to / ?

Comment: No, you would not, root is root.